# Why am I getting keyboard letter repeats with Chrome and not Firefox?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, repeat

When I type in chrome I sometimes get letter repeats like ttttttttthis

It doesn't happen in Firefox or other apps

I am using Ubuntu 23.10 and Chrome Version 122.0.6261.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Started a couple of weeks ago

I logged out of lastpass but it didn't help

I tried disabling all other extensions but it didn't help

I tried turning off 'developer mode' but it also didn't help

I also get brief mouse freezes which might be related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A system reboot fixed the issues for both keyboard and mouse.

I don't know why.  However if you are experiencing the issue this may help you too.